# Error in report query with image

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

When I execute this report sql, which gets personal data and an image of the user, it gives me the following error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

```
SELECT
ID, 
NAME,
ADDRESS,  
DECODE(GENDER,'M','MALE','F','FEMALE') as GENDER, 
DECODE(nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(IMG),0), 0, null,
            '<img style="border: 4px solid #CCC; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px;" '||
                 'src="'||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P2_IMG',ID)||'" height="75" width="75" '||
                 'alt="Product Image" title="Product Image" />')  IMG 
FROM USMAN
```

Comment: Why tagged [tag:mysql] *and* [tag:oracle-apex]/[tag:plsql]?

Comment: Coz i am developing in APEX....and query is same in all...

Comment: Very strange query... Why do you need this decode in SOQL? What is the problem to retrieve all data from DB and only after this do all coding/decoding?

Comment: @Chiz because OP probably wants to get this info into an orace apex report. The gender decode is not necessarily required as it could be resolved by a list of values defined in the column attributes. The img tag html generation less so, because of how `apex_util.get_blob_file_src` works.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of your decode on the blob column, which produces a number, compares a number, and gets a char as a default value.
You could try

```
DECODE(TO_CHAR(nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(IMG),0)), '0', null, '<img ... />')
```